# Debian no aparece en la lista de Sistemas Operativos en las opciones de arranque de la BIOS (Windows 10)

Tags: windows10

Hace unas semanas me compré dos tarjetas SD para instalar Debian 11 para un par de asignaturas. En la primera instalé Ubuntu y  en la segunda instalé esta imagen .iso:

- firmware-11.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso

Funcionaba bien, en la BIOS aparecía debian para arrancar y estuve trabajando en ella durante todo este tiempo.

El problema surgió al formatear la primera SD e instalar Debian 11. En esta segunda tarjeta instalé esta imagen .iso:

- debian-11.1.0-amd64-netinst.iso

La instalación se completó sin problemas y en la BIOS aparecía debian para arrancar también.

Pero al insertar la segunda tarjeta SD ya no aparece debian en la lista y no tengo ni idea de lo que puede haber pasado.

[image: En la BIOS no aparece debian (segunda tarjeta) y aún aparece ubuntu (primera tarjeta)]

Aparte no se porqué sigue mostrándome la opción de Ubuntu.

Si por favor hay alguien que me pueda ayudar se lo agradeceré enormemente ya que estoy perdiendo muchisimo tiempo con esta tontería (porque seguro que lo es) y tengo cosas que entregar. Espero también no haber perdido todo lo que tenia en la segunda tarjeta...

Para terminar si hay algo mas de información que se necesite no dudéis en indicarlo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Por regla general los programadores sabemos un poco de informática general porque bueno, usamos ordenadores... Pero no sé por qué mucha gente cree que los programadores somos informáticos de sistemas :/ De hecho, conozco unos cuantos programadores que saben tanto de sistemas como mi abuela, imagínate! Lo que quiero decir, es que esta pregunta fijo fijo fijísimo que te la responden muy bien en alguna comunidad que se dedique precisamente a configurar sistemas... Podrías probar en [serverFault](https://serverfault.com/), que son unos cracks de eso. Si no, pues con suerte alguien te responde.

Comment: Creo que tal vez en esta comunidad puedas obtener mas ayuda https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/ aqui no enfocamos a problemas de programacion y desarrollo de software, saludos

Comment: Hola. Muchas gracias por responder y por compartir esa web. La verdad sabía que aqui no encajaba mucho la pregunta pero no sabia muy bien donde postearla y al tener ya cuenta aquí pues me decidí a intentarlo.